# Dynamic Subdomains with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, dns, subdomain

I have been trying to find a way to do this for the last 2 days and it's driving me crazy.

I need to dinamically use subdomain.mediagrex.com to show mediagrex.com/index.php?id={subdomain}

I read a lot  of threads about ti here on stackoverflow and I have the following in my htaccess which seems to be correct:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mediagrex\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?id=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mediagrex\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?id=%1 [L]
```

I also added an A record in my domain registrar as *.mediagrex.com pointing to my server ip.

However when I access subdomain.mediagrex.com I get an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the error is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, then your wildcard subdomain DNS record is not configured properly

Comment: I have the following: https://i.imgur.com/vdXcRi3.jpg any idea what's wrong?